# Problem with finding the data points from a set of equations (Least Squares method)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, approximation

Yesterday on my IT lectures I was introduced to the "Least Squares" method. Obviously it is all about finding such an $F$ that $F(x)=a_0\phi_0(x)+a_1\phi_1(x)+...+a_n\phi_n(x)$ and $R=R(a_0,a_1,...a_n)= \sum_{k=0}^{m}{[f(x_k)-y_k]^2}$ reaches its minimum.

We also asummed that our base set of functions are monomials: ($\phi_i(x)=x^{i}$) The derivation seemed pretty clear until we came across the first "overdetermined" set of equations. $\begin{cases}
a+2b=6 \\[2ex]
2a-b=8 \\[2ex] 2a+3b=-4
\end{cases}$

After using the Least Squares method I got that the best approximating polynomial is $f(x)=\frac{86}{33}-\frac{52}{33}x$

My question is: how can I retrieve the given data points $(x_k, y_k)$ from the above set of equations? Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: why do you think you can go back to the data?

Comment: The task was given without any other additional remarks. We just had to find the best approximating polynomial for the overdetermined set of equations. Since the method is used for approximating a given set of points with a ceratin function it seems that it would be pointless to find that function if we do not know the data. There must be some method to know what I am approximating. Otherwise the problem would seem very impractical.

Comment: So typically your overdetermined equations come from your data with an additional equation for each pair of x and y data. So you could imagine that your data was generated by three examples with y1=6, y2=8 and y3=-4. Typically, b is used to describe an intercept and would have a coefficient of 1 for each and I assum the coefficients in front of your a's are your x values. Your notation is a bit hard to decipher.